# Tellurium vs Selenium : Compare

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium for sometime and doing good with it. I would like to try Tellurium. Searched and find only few questions about that. I would like to know the following

1. What is the main advantages of using Tellurium?
2. How it is different Selenium+Groovy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tellurium is DSL(Domain-specific language) for Selenium. It was made to make Selenium easier to use. If you like Tellurium language better than use that.

in this document you can see how its different
http://code.google.com/p/aost/wiki/UserGuide070Introduction?tm=6

If we think Selenium as the "C" language, Tellurium is like the "C++" language, which uses a different testing concept. There are couple advantages to describe the UI elements as a UI module.
Tellurium emphasizes the decoupling of UI from test code. The structured test code makes Tellurium easier to maintain and refactor.

Comment: Can you comment on how stable it is? any known issues etc

Comment: I had problem with installing firefox plugin, im not sure about it :|

Answer (score 4):

decoupling is only one advantage of Tellurium. If you read some document about tellurium, you should know that Tellurium is expressive. You know what UI you are testing against, which is good for test maintenance. With the release of 0.7.0, tellurium is diverting from Selenium with many new concepts such as group locating and tellurium widgets, to name a few.

The following wiki covered the comparison between Selenium and Tellurium:

http://code.google.com/p/aost/wiki/TelluriumAWrapOfSelenium

Tellurium IDE is out now, you can try it out. More details on
http://code.google.com/p/aost/wiki/TelluriumIde080RC1

Comment: In Selenium, I can add a location strategy using jquery and separate java code and locators to make my tests run even if the UI changes. In initial look Tellurium doesn't offer lot of things. However, I'll play it with for some more and comment on it.

Comment: We just have an InfoQ article published. Here is the URL: http://www.infoq.com/articles/tellurium_intro

Answer (score 2):

I also would like to tell that decoupling the UI elements from the Implementation of the core should be a **standard practice**. In that, **Tellurium** is nothing new.

WebDriver for example has his **PageFactory** ( http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory  ).

So based on that **Tellurium** is really nothing new. Alas if your framework is robust enough to uphold long endeavors and can stand the iron teeth of time then it really is only a questions of '*like*' which one you use.

Your framework should be good enough no matter the technology wrapped around it or in it for that matter.

Gergely.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using rational functional tester where the UI objects are stored in object maps(xml files),private or shared xml files. I can tell you that its a nightmare to maintain those files when you have lots of scripts and you have to make a little change in the object map because a UI changed.

I prefer the java way, i agreed the comments "i would like to tell that decoupling the UI elements from the Implementation of the core should be a standard practice. In that, Tellurium is nothing new.

Answer (score -6):

Selenium has is free and has a very nice [Firefox Plugin](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/). In my point of view Selenium is a de-facto-standard. Selenuim has a very clear and simple syntax.

But I don't really understand what [Tellurium](http://code.google.com/p/aost/wiki/TenMinutesToTellurium) is.

Comment: must be a glitch in Stack Overflows reputation system :)